# Hibernate composite key with foreigh references from different table

Tags: hibernate, composite-primary-key

I have the following table structure

```
         ID:detail_id                 event_id:event_id
Detail   -------------> Association  -----------------> Event
------                  -----------                    -----------
ID(PK)                  detail_id (PK)(FK)             event_id (PK)           
                        event_id (PK)(FK)
```

Mapping between Detail table to Association table is Many to One.
Mapping between Association table to Event table Many to One.

```
Detail table:
@Table(name = "Detail")
class Detail{
    private Association association;
    @MapsId("detailId")
    @manytoone
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumn="detail_id")
    public Association getAssociation(){
     return association
    }
    //setter
}
```

AssociationID class - for composite key

```
@Embeddable
class AssociationID implements Serializable{
 private Long detailId;
 private Long eventId;

 @column(name = "detail_id")
 public Long getDetailId(){
    return detailId;
 }

 @column(name = "event_id")
 public Long getEventId(){
    return eventId;
 }
}

@Table(name="Association")
class Association{

    private AssociationID associationId;
    private Event event;
    private Set<Detail> detailCollection;

    @EmbeddedId
    public AssociationID getAssociationId(){
        return associationId;
    }
    @MapsId("eventId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="eventId", referencedColumnName="event_id")
    public Event getEvent(){
         return event;
    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="association")
    public Set<FundDetail> getFundDetail(){
         return detailCollection;
    }


}
@Table(name="Event")
class Event{
 private long eventId
 @OneToMany(mappedby="event")
 private Association association;
}
```

I am getting error - referencedColumnNames (detail_id) of detail.association referencing Association not mapped to a single property. Is it because I am just mapping detailId and not eventId in composite key? If so the problem is the eventId references another table(Event) and it is not present in Detail table. So please let me know how to associate the fields in composite key if it references from 2 different tables.

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example. Besides where is the question?

Comment: Question is just below the image. How to handle composite key with foreign references from 2 different tables and I’m getting the hibernate error not mapped with single property with the code above.

Comment: What is your question? Explain the arrows & their numbers on your diagram. Why are both arrows to the right? What do you mean, "is there is a composite key in Association table with foreign references from two different tables"? Are you asking about the diagram, or the code, or what? "how to handle" is unhelpfully vague. (Please talk about FKs referencing (a PK/UNIQUE), not being from or to, because we don't know which one of those means referencing to you.) Please be more clear. Give a cut & paste & runnable [mre] showing your problem, change your code into an example. What error message?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited and added more details.